# вылетает ошибка, хотя если в отдельном классе запускать, то все нормально

Tags: java, javafx, jsoup

вот сам код где ошибка происходит

```
package application;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ControllerVxod {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane piskuStroi;

    @FXML
    private Label labelV;

    @FXML
    private Button lod;

    @FXML
    private Button ly;

    @FXML
    private Button Vixod;

    @FXML
    private Label Mo;

    @FXML
    void initialize() throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://minecraftonly.ru/minecraft/")
                .userAgent("Chrome/4.0.249.0 Safari/532.5")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
Elements listNews = doc.select("#sidebar-server > a:nth-child(3)");
        for (Element element : listNews.select("a")) {
            System.out.println(element.text());
        Mo.setText(element.text());Mo.setText(listNews.select("a").get(2).text());}

        piskuStroi.setMaxSize(583,387);
        piskuStroi.setPrefSize(583,387);
        piskuStroi.setMinSize(583,387);
        lod.setOnAction(event ->{try {
            MyGETRequest();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            ZipXuina();


        });
        Vixod.setOnAction(event ->{.........
```

вот класс где все работает

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TestEpta {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://minecraftonly.ru/minecraft/")
                .userAgent("Chrome/4.0.249.0 Safari/532.5")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
Elements listNews = doc.select("#sidebar-server");
        for (Element element : listNews.select("a"))
            System.out.println(element.text());System.out.println(listNews.select("a").get(2).text());
    }

}
```

```
июл 31, 2019 7:08:07 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.221
Classic 1.12.2 44 / 100
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/%d0%90%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84%d0%b0/eclipse-workspace/Piskostroi/bin/application/Voshel.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at application.ControllerMine.lambda$0(ControllerMine.java:71)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.ControllerVxod.initialize(ControllerVxod.java:67)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: какая ошибка то?

Comment: извините, забыл добавить, сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего Label `Mo == null`. Это может из-за того что в fxml разметке не верно указан id этого Label. Проверьте задан ли id этого Label в fxml разметке таким образом: `fx:id="Mo"`

Comment: за одно проверьте действительно ли Mo == null (можно просто в консоли вывести)

Comment: нет, если я убераю  `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://minecraftonly.ru/minecraft/")
                .userAgent("Chrome/4.0.249.0 Safari/532.5")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
Elements listNews = doc.select("#sidebar-server > a:nth-child(3)");
     for (Element element : listNews.select("a")) {
            System.out.println(element.text());
     Mo.setText(element.text());Mo.setText(listNews.select("a").get(2).text());}`\

Comment: то все прекрасно работает без ошибок, и кст надпись не меняется+ там остается на этом лейбле "Mo"

Comment: Все прекрасно работает скорее всего из-за удаления `Mo.setText()`, попробуй убрать только `Mo.setText(element.text());Mo.setText(listNews.select("a").get(2).text());`. Надпись не меняется, из-за ошибки. Программа на этом месте прекращает выполнение метода, но окно не закрывает

Comment: да, в консоль выводит, а мне нужно чтобы в мой лейбл это писалось

Comment: в ответе все написано

Comment: извините, я просто просмотрел ваш ответ но, не проверил есть ли fx:id, а его и не было, хотя я через Scenebuilder сохранял, но увы, не сохранилось(